# Missing WelcomePage title in the breadcrumb?

Tags: master-page, custom-masterpage, breadcrumb

I am using SP 2013 on-premises. I implementet the breadcrumb in the masterpage as follow:

```
<!--MS:<asp:SiteMapPath runat="server" SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPXmlContentMapProvider" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false" NodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbNode" CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbCurrentNode" RootNodeStyle-CssClass="breadcrumbRootNode" HideInteriorRootNodes="true" SkipLinkText=""/>-->
```

I can see the site Titles and the Publishing page titles in the breadcrumb. The welcomepage is also a publishing page, but I dont see the title in the breadcrumb. Why do I have this behavior? Is this by design that the Welcomepage is excluded in the breadcrumb?

Example:

Title of my site : MyCompany
I have 3 publishing pages in the pages library:

- TestPage1
- TestPage2
- TestPage3

**Welcomepage:** TestPage1

**On the welcome page I see now in the breadcrumb:** MyCompanyName

**I expect:** MyCompanyName > TestPage1

**When I go to TestPage2 or TestPage3 I see:**

MyCompanyName > TestPage2

MyCompanyName > TestPage3

Comment: Can you attach image?

Comment: See updated topic content.

Comment: Check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66740/why-does-my-default-pages-title-not-display-on-breadcrumb

Answer (score 0):

If you are using one of the themes from SharePoint your breadcrumb icon will not appear as it should, to get it back add the script below before the closing tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("GlobalBreadCrumbNavPopout-anchor").innerHTML='<img style="border-width:0;position:absolute;left:-215px !important;top:-120px !important;" alt="Navigate Up" src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=27">';
</script>
```

Make sure you have removed the **style= display:none** from the below div in your master page.

```
<div class="ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox" style="display:none;">
```

Comment: I see the breadcrumb. I only missing the welcomepage title in the breadcrumb. Other publishing pages and sites are showed in the breadcrumb

Comment: so in welcome page do you see the xslt for breadcrumb in developer tool?

Answer (score 0):

if you have enabled breadcrumb for the publishing page, then for the welcome page will show only the Site collection title, but not the breadcrumb for the page. if you analyse it, welcome page has the page which will open by default and from welcome page we are redirecting to another page and on this page breadcrumb will show like "Site collection Title -> Test Page 1", and when you will click to the Site Collection name it will go the welcome page.and from welcome page you can not go back anywhere.

**you can do one thing for more clarification** - set "Test Page 2" as a welcome Page and you find that on welcome page it will show only site collection name and for the "Test Page 1" and "Test Page 3", breadcrumb will show as expected.